# Linking errors: <LNK1120> <LNK2020> Implement one serialization data class in C++

Tags: c++, .net, visual-studio-2010

I don't know why I've a linking erro in the project. The header and the implementation code for the class in my opinion are correctly implemented. I will appreciate your collaboration dear friends.

## Objetive

Implement one serialization data class in C++

## Erros Menssage

Error   2   error LNK1120: 1 unresolved externals   C:\Users...\SerializationTest.exe  1   1   SerializationTest

Error   1   error LNK2020: unresolved token (06000001) 
SerializationExtensions ^>::Serialize C:\Users...\SerializationTest.obj  SerializationTest

## Here the code

### file: SerializationExtensions.h

```
#ifndef __SERIALIZATION_EXTENSIONS_H__
#define __SERIALIZATION_EXTENSIONS_H__


template<class T>
public ref class SerializationExtensions
{
public:
    static System::String^ Serialize(T obj);
    static T Deserialize(System::String^ serialized);
};


#endif // __SERIALIZATION_EXTENSIONS_H__
```

### file: SerializationExtensions.cpp

```
#include "stdafx.h"
#include "SerializationExtensions.h"

#using <System.Runtime.Serialization.dll>

using namespace System::IO;
using namespace System::Xml;
using namespace System::Runtime::Serialization;

template<class T>
System::String^ SerializationExtensions<T>::Serialize(T obj)
{
    DataContractSerializer^ serializer = gcnew DataContractSerializer(obj->GetType());
    StringWriter^ writer = gcnew StringWriter();
    XmlTextWriter^ stm = gcnew XmlTextWriter(writer);
    serializer->WriteObject(stm, obj);
    return writer->ToString();
}

template<class T>
T SerializationExtensions<T>::Deserialize(System::String^ serialized)
{
    DataContractSerializer^ serializer = gcnew DataContractSerializer(typeof(T));
    StringReader^ reader = gcnew StringReader(serialized);
    XmlTextReader^ stm = gcnew XmlTextReader(reader);
    return (T)serializer->ReadObject(stm);
}
```

### file: SerializationTest.cpp

```
// SerializationTest.cpp : main project file.

#include "stdafx.h"
#include "SerializationExtensions.h"


using namespace System::Collections::Generic;
using namespace System;


int main(array<System::String ^> ^args)
{

    Dictionary<System::String^, System::Double>^ teste = gcnew Dictionary<System::String^, System::Double>();
    teste->Add("Teste1",2);
    teste->Add("Teste2",4);

    Console::WriteLine(SerializationExtensions<Dictionary<System::String^, System::Double>^>::Serialize(teste));

    return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Template classes need to have their definition inside the header, so it's visible to all TU that want to specialize the class.

Move the implementations to `SerializationExtensions.h`.

Comment: You're rigth, it works ! Now I understand, templates can't be seperated in .cpp and .h files. Thank's Luchian

Comment: @RafaelCosta yup. There are tons of questions like this on SO, that's why I didn't expand my answer. The downside is they're not easy to find, if you don't know exactly what to look for.